How do I replace the forEach function in apps script when wanting to send emails listed in my google sheet?
I have a google sheet that serves as a waitlist and I wanted to be able to send update emails weekly to let people know what position they are in the waitlist. I am very new to apps script and coding and I found a solution on a question asked in 2022 in a similar situation. I tried to implement the code, but it uses forEach and it seems that is no longer a function. Any suggestions on how to best do this? I have linked the code below.
Spreadsheet I am currently using
Here is the code from the post
function newmatchEmail() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet1=ss.getSheetByName('Active Student List');
var data=sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();

data.forEach(function(row,col){
if (col == '') return;
if (row[0] == '') return; //If ColA is empty skip
if (row [6] == false) return; //Skip if the checkbox is not checked in Col G
if (row [5] == 'YES') return; //Skip if the email has been sent in ColF

var info = row[0];
var name = row[2];
var studentemail = row[3];

var tutoremail = row[4];
var subject = "Student Opening Request";
var message = "Thank You So Much\n\nHere is the basic info: " + `${info}` 
 + "\nStudent Name: " + `${name}`
 + "\nStudent Email: " + `${studentemail}`
 + "\n\nPlease do not hesitate to ask questions";

MailApp.sendEmail(tutoremail, subject, message);

data.getRange(col + 1, 6).setValue('YES'); //Imprint YES in ColF once the email has been sent

data.getRange('G2:G').setValue(false); //Reset the checkboxes in ColG to null after emails/process is           completed
});

}

And here is my adjusted code for my purposes
function newmatchEmail() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet1=ss.getSheetByName('Extension or Waitlist Form');
 var data=sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();

data.forEach(function(row,col){
if (col == '') return;
if (row[0] == '') return; 
if (row [3] == 'NO') return; 

var info = row[0];
var name = row[1];


var email = row[2];
var subject = "Waitlist Update";
var message = "Hello" + `${name}` 
+ "You are currently number " + `${info}` + "on the waitlist for an appointment.";

MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);


});

}


The question doesn't include enough details, i.e., it's not clear if you have created a bounded script or a stand alone script. Also, what makes you think that forEach is no longer a function?

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Two answers have been posted in response to your question. Please review the answer if it correctly solves your issue. If it does, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and/or upvote the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that their issue can be resolved. For further details, you may read the article on how to accept the answer.

If forEach doesn't work for some reason try a classical for loop:
  for (var rowIndex in data) {
    var row = data[rowIndex];

    if (rowIndex == 0) continue; // Skip header row if there is one
    if (row[0] == '') continue; // If ColA is empty, skip
    if (row[6] == false) continue; // Skip if the checkbox is not checked in ColG
    if (row[5] == 'YES') continue; // Skip if the email has been sent in ColF

    ....
  }

In case this also doesn't work, try putting in console/print statements or other debugging methods to see where the script doesn't work as intended.

forEach is  indeed still an Array function. The problm lies in the code within the loop.

Case Sensitive String
forEach still works as a Function in Google Apps Script.
I've tested the code and checked the screenshot. The string being in all caps is what's causing the loop to not be properly utilized. The screenshot indicates "No" on column D and the code contains "NO" in all caps. (Case sensitivity being the cause)
See:
if (row [3] == 'NO') return; 
I can suggest 2 things: You can use OR logical operator or use a tickbox for a "True" or "False" parameter check.
Suggested parameter for Column D being checkbox (screenshot)
Reference for the suggestion  : JS Operators
